# How can I delete any Label (either for vertex or edge) in Apache AGE?

Tags: graph-databases, apache-age

I have tried:

```
SELECT drop_vlabel('graph','vName');

SELECT delete_vlabel('graph','vName');
```

But they give error.

```
ERROR:  function drop_vlabel(unknown, unknown) does not exist
ERROR:  function delete_vlabel(unknown, unknown) does not exist
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to drop a label (either of edge or of a vertex), use

```
SELECT drop_label('graph', 'vName');
```

It should display something like

> NOTICE: label "graph"."vName" has been dropped

The above notice shows that label has been dropped successfully.
You can also crosscheck using the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM ag_catalog.ag_label;
```

This table should not have the label that you just dropped

Reference: regression test [here](https://github.com/apache/age/blob/master/regress/expected/catalog.out)

Answer (score 0):

This feature currently under development in apache AGE. See the issue [here](https://github.com/apache/age/issues/717) and [here](https://github.com/apache/age/issues/464).

So for now what you can do is [delete](https://github.com/apache/age/issues/387) that node/edge and then recreate all the node/edge and its connection